# How to use localStorage after using color picker to change --var of :root

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just spent a whole afternoon on my problem, I am new to JavaScript and I want do something :

I want the user to be able to select and change the main-color in the page.

I added a color picker in my HTML with :

```
<input type="color" id="colorID" oninput="changeColor()">
```

Then I took this code on Internet :

```
// on input, get value and save it as 'storedValue'
function changeColor() {
  var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
  localStorage.setItem('storedValue', document.body.style.backgroundColor = userColor);
}

// if there is a value stored, update color picker and background color
if(localStorage.storedValue) {
  document.getElementById('colorID').value = localStorage.storedValue;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor      = localStorage.storedValue;
}
```

I want replace "document.body.style.backgroundColor" by my --main-color: #fff; of my :root.
I tried a lot of things, replacing document.body by document.documentElement... Nothing wants to work !

Comment: Your title mentions a var in :root but you seem to be trying to update the body style directly without changing any var. Which do you want to do?

Comment: The code I put upper works, but in my case I want change my custom var to my CSS :root. My code above is an exemple to show what I want to do

Comment: There is no usage of a CSS var in the code you have provided so I'm afraid I am lost.

Comment: Ahah yeah sorry, I want change the backgroundColor modification by a CSS var modification, I am trying to figure out my problem, I know i'm not clear

Comment: So you are actually trying to modify a var rather than the background color directly, is that right? Have you investigated el.style.setProperty?

Comment: Yes exactly ! No i didn't, what should i do ?

Comment: Read up about changing CSS variables using JS - e.g. at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Call an invoked function that will run immedietly after the page loads
(function(){
if(localStorage.getItem("storedValue")){
  document.getElementById('colorID').value = localStorage.storedValue;
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--main-color', userColor) = localStorage.storedValue;
})();

// on input, get value and save it as 'storedValue'
    function changeColor() {
      var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
      localStorage.setItem('storedValue', document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--main-color', userColor));
    }
    
    // if there is a value stored, update color picker and background color
    if(localStorage.storedValue) {
      document.getElementById('colorID').value = localStorage.storedValue;
      document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--main-color', userColor) = localStorage.storedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply, I solved my problem. Your code looks good !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because writing/reading in the local/session storage, needs to be done with stringify/parse methods:

```
// in your HTML file, add a hidden input
<input type="hidden" value="your_css_variable_value" id="myId"/>

// in JS file, query that element and get its value
const bgColor = document.querySelector('#myId').value;

// on input, get value and save it as 'storedValue'
function changeColor() {
  var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor      = userColor;
  localStorage.setItem('storedValue', JSON.stringify(userColor));
}

// if there is a value stored, update color picker and background color
if (localStorage.getItem('storedValue')) {
  const savedColor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedValue'));
  document.getElementById('colorID').value = savedColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor      = savedColor;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but right now how can I replace the last line for my custom var in my CSS :root ?

Comment: I don't think JSON.stringify is necessary, we are not storing array/object, just a simple string

Comment: Please be a bit specific, where is your --main-color defined? Is it a variable inside a scss/less file? Is this a fallback color that you want to revert to?

Comment: My --main-color is defined into my style.css. I'm working on a WordPress plugin and the file is in the /assets !

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. The initial background color is stored now in the `bgColor` variable, which should be updated when the page is loaded, from the hidden input's value

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to get the value from the local Storage:

```
function changeColor() {
      var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
localStorage.setItem('storedValue', document.body.style.backgroundColor = userColor);
}
    
    if(localStorage.storedValue) {
        document.getElementById('colorID').value = localStorage.storedValue;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor      = localStorage.storedValue;
    }
```

Correct way to to get the Stored value from the local Storage is:

```
 function changeColor() {
          var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
          document.body.style.backgroundColor=userColor;
          localStorage.setItem('storedValue', userColor);
        }
    
        if(localStorage.getItem("storedValue")) {
             let storedValue=localStorage.getItem("storedValue");
             document.getElementById('colorID').value = storedValue;
             document.body.style.backgroundColor      = storedValue;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this post, thanks to everyone who replied.

My first question showed an exemple and I lost some people.
This is what I really want to do :

```
// on input, get value and save it as 'storedValue'
function changeColor() {
  var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
  localStorage.setItem('storedValue', document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--main-color', userColor));
}

// if there is a value stored, update color picker and background color
if(localStorage.storedValue) {
  document.getElementById('colorID').value = localStorage.storedValue;
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--main-color', userColor) = localStorage.storedValue;
}
```

My only problem now is : It does not save when I refresh the page.
I'm so close ! What should I change to make this code works ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
inputColor.addEventListener("input", changeColor, false);

function changeColor() {
    debugger;
  var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
  localStorage.setItem('storedValue', JSON.stringify(userColor));

    // if there is a value stored, update color picker and background color
if (localStorage.getItem('storedValue')) {
  const savedColor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedValue'));
  document.body.style.backgroundColor      = savedColor;
}
    
}
```